# Migration from Oracle to MySQL or PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I want to migrate the data source of my Java web application from oracle to either MySQL or PostgreSQL. Oracle database size is huge and contains Large objects as well. Please suggest which would be the better choice? Please explain with some issues, example and points.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is much more similar to Oracle than MySQL is. Significant difference still exist, but you'd probably find it to me an easier migration, and more similar behaviour by the database.

Answer (score 0):

Large objects as BLOB might give you some problems as Oracle has some vendor specific implementation which is often used in Java code. I.e check you import statements where BLOB is used. For some more see here: http://www-css.fnal.gov/dsg/external/freeware/mysql-vs-pgsql.html

Comment: Thanks for you valuable suggestions. So which database PostgreSQL or MySQL should I use?

Comment: You are to generic, it is hard to find a specific answers to a general question. Traditionally PostgresSql had smaller community and bad documentation while it was a good implemenation most SQL functionality, while MySql had a big community and good documentation but was poor at SQL functionality. Both have now improved nowadays, hence Mysql with innodb gives you lot of SQL functionlatiy while PostGresSql has a larger community and better docs nowaday. If you need clustering then I have heard that MySql is quicker and easier to set up than PostGresSql.